# PHP $_SESSION overwritten variable not passing to next page

Tags: php, session-variables, register-globals

Problem: in the code below when I move from page from sandbox1 to sandbox2 the new value of $_SESSION[page_name] is not being passed on and reverts back to the initial value of index. If after entering the page I reload the page the new value seems to magically show up. Is there something wrong with the code? Could you explain why the new value of $_SESSION is not propagating?

**Page index.php**

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['page']="index";
echo "This page: ".$_SESSION['page']."<br><br>";
?>
```

**Page sandbox1.php**

```
<?php
session_start(); 
echo "From page: ".$_SESSION['page']."<br>";    
$_SESSION['page']="Sandbox1";
echo "This page: ".$_SESSION['page']."<br><br>";
?>
```

**Page sandbox2.php**

```
<?php
session_start(); 
echo "From page: ".$_SESSION['page']."<br>";
$_SESSION['page']="Sandbox2";
echo "This page: ".$_SESSION['page']."<br><br>";
?>
```

On loading index.php it outputs:

> This page: index

as expected.

Hyperlink from index.php to Sandbox1 output

> From page:  index
>
> This page: Sandbox1

(new value `$_SESSION['page']`) as expected.

Hyperlink from Sandbox1 to Sandbox2 output:

> From page:  index

(`$_SESSION` revert to value index) expected to see

> From page: sandbox1
>
> This page: Sandbox2

(new value)as expected.

Additional information PHP version 5.3.  Register global is set to  "OFF"

Comment: You called `session_start()` after checking.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I did move session_start() to the first line in both sandbox1 and sandbox2 with the same result. The new value of $_SESSION is reverting to index.

Answer (score 6):

On sandbox1 and sandbox 2, move `session_start()` above the line that reads

```
echo "From page: ".$_SESSION['page']."<br>";
```

Comment: Len_D -  thank you ... the code I shared is the first line of code in each page. Just as you see it all the html is below the php code shown.

Comment: I did move session_start() to the first line in both sandbox1 and sandbox2 with the same result. The new value of $_SESSION is still reverting to value index. (see corrected code in question) –

Comment: Sometimes there can be a delay in writing the session vars. Try this:
After setting the session var for page, in each script, add this line:
session_write_close(); and then check the value of tghe session var.

Comment: Len_D I try your suggestion of adding session_write_close(); to all three pages. No change same results I also tested the pages in iPage and GoDaddy servers and got the same results. I also tested the pages in PHP 4.3 and 5.2 in both of this versions of PHP the $_SESSION parameter was not passed at all.

Comment: Len_D please see the solution to the problem below.  Thank you for your suggestions they help me to make the application code more robust.

Comment: Glad you got it. I was going to go back to working on your issue today. I was off work yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved. The PHP code is functioning correctly. The problem seems to only affect IE 11 and is related to the refresh cycle of this browser. Other browsers displayed the expected out. The problem was correct by changing the Apache server .htaccess file to suppress catching in test files used for debugging.

Investigating whether the problem is with IE-11 or specific test-bench configuration of this browser.